# How to add a comment to a work item using Visual Studio Team Services REST API

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to add a comment to a work item in Visual Studio Team Services using the REST API?

I've checked the [work item doc](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-work-item-overview-vsi) and [fields doc](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-work-item-fields-vsi) but I couldn't see anything in the fields JSON which looked like it's the comments field.

The scenario I'm trying to achieve is CCing an email to [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) and having the body of the email added as a comment on the work item in VSO.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but JSON doesn't support comments. You'd have to add that as a key in the object.

Comment: There is a fields endpoint which lists all the work item fields in your VSO account.  I checked the JSON response and there didn't seem to be an entry for the work item comments field.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Following @tzachs tip, this is the API call to add a comment (or history entry in VSO jargon):

```
PATCH https://{account}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=1.0-preview.2
```

JSON payload:

```
[  
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.History",
    "value": "Comment from VSO REST API"
  }
]
```

**Note**: If you want to add multiple comments, you need to issue separate patch requests, or else the last one "wins".

Comment: Can you please explain, How I separate patch request for multiple comments?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this, but I think instead of sending one request containing an array of three comments, you'd send three requests with one comment in each.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The field you're looking for is 'History', see example here:
http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-work-item-work-items-vsi#updateafield

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259), and provide the link for reference. Please add the relevant content directly to your answer, as it'll prevent link rot.