# TFS comment "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, postman

I am following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

I am POSTing to <URL>/_apis/wit/workItems/11351/comments with a body of

```
[
  {
    "text": "Postman: This is a test comment, please ignore."
  }
]
```

The URL seems to match the documentation and returns

```
{
    "totalCount": 0,
    "fromRevisionCount": 0,
    "count": 0,
    "comments": []
}
```

so it seems to be valid.

I get this in response though:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": {
        "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value you're using for `<URL>`? Are you including the API version in your query string? Are you using on-prem TFS, or Azure DevOps? If on-prem TFS, **what version**?

Comment: The URL is an internal corporate server. I am not specifying the version. The TFS is on-premesis. I believe the version is 5.1

Comment: There is no TFS "5.1". The version is a year. 2015, 2018, etc.

Comment: "About" says Version Dev17.M153.5, which looks like 2019

Comment: That's useful information. Can you please answer the other questions I asked?

Comment: What questions have I not answered?

Comment: I asked you to provide the URL. You can redact sensitive information, but seeing the full API path, i.e. `http://my-internal-server/tfs/DefaultCollection/my-project/_api/...` is useful. Also, make sure you *do* include the API version in the query string; it is important.

Comment: https://<server>/tfs/TFSTeam/_apis/wit/workItems/11351/comments

Comment: If I put ?api-version=6.0, I get "The requested REST API version of 6.0 is out of range for this server. The latest REST API version this server supports is 5.1." If I put ?api-version=5.1, I get "page not found".

Comment: What about `6.0-preview.3`?

Comment: "The requested REST API version of 6.0 is out of range for this server. The latest REST API version this server supports is 5.1."

Comment: And `5.1-preview.3`?

Comment: "Page not found".

Comment: I followed this answer's instructions, which worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895435/how-to-add-a-comment-to-a-work-item-using-visual-studio-team-services-rest-api